# Find all substrings with at least one group

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I try to find in a string all substring that meet the condition.

Let's say we've got string:

```
s = 'some text 1a 2a 3 xx sometext 1b yyy some text 2b.'
```

I need to apply search pattern {(one (group of words), two (another group of words), three (another group of words)), word}. First three positions are optional, but there should be at least one of them. If so, I need a word after them.
Output should be:

```
2a  1a  3 xx
1b  yyy
2b
```

I wrote this expression:

```
find_it = re.compile(r"((?P<one>\b1a\s|\b1b\s)|" +
                    r"(?P<two>\b2a\s|\b2b\s)|" +
                    r"(?P<three>\b3\s|\b3b\s))+" +
                    r"(?P<word>\w+)?")
```

Every group contain set or different words (not 1a, 1b). And I can't mix them into one group. It should be `None` if group is empty. Obviously the result is wrong.

```
find_it.findall(s)
> 2a  1a  2a   3 xx
> 1b  1b    yyy
```

I am grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
>>> reg=re.compile('((?:(?:[12][ab]|3b?)\s?)+(?:\w+|\.))')
>>> reg.findall(s)
['1a 2a 3 xx', '1b yyy', '2b.']
```

Here I just concise your regex by using character class and modifier `?`.The following regex is contain 2 part :

```
[12][ab]|3b?
```

`[12][ab]` will match `1a`,`1b`,`2a`,`2b` and `3b?` will match `3b` and `3`.

And if you don't want the dot at the end of `2b` you can use following regex using a [*positive look ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that is more general than preceding regex (because making `\s` optional is not a good idea in first group):

```
>>> reg=re.compile('((?:(?:[12][ab]|3b?)\s)+\w+|(?:(?:[12][ab]|3b?))+(?=\.|$))')
>>> reg.findall(s)
['1a 2a 3 xx', '1b yyy', '2b']
```

Also if your numbers and example substrings are just instances you can use `[0-9][a-z]` as a general regex :

```
>>> reg=re.compile('((?:[0-9][a-z]?\s)+\w+|(?:[0-9][a-z]?)+(?=\.|$))')
>>> reg.findall(s)
['1a 2a 3 xx', '1b yyy', '5h 9 7y examole', '2b']
```

Comment: I'm sorry! Probably my question is incorrectly defined, but 1a, 1b, 2a, 3 etc - are totally different words. I just combined them into groups to simplify view.

Comment: It works). But in this way all groups are equal. And what if I need to distinguish them?

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova It's hard to imagine what you want can you pls add an example to your question?

Comment: If we change [0-9][a-z] to some words, it doesn't work.  `s = 'some text catch-1-me catch-2-me catch-3-me xx sometext catch-1-me yyy some text catch-2-me.'`   `re_numbers = re.compile(ur'((?:catch-1-me|catch-2-me|catch-3-me?\s)+\w+|(?:catch-1-me|catch-2-me|catch-3-me?)+(?=\.|$))')`

Comment: @KatrinaMalakhova So in this case you need to put a desire regex instead of  `[0-9][a-z]`  so in this example you can use `\w+-\d-\w+` or `atch-\d-me`